# Xamarin Android no longer printing MONO GC log messages

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, mono

I have a Xamarin.Forms app that runs on Android, which has been in development for several years. Until recently, when running the app I would see MONO GC messages whenever a garbage collection occurred, similar to the following:

```
04-11 16:46:22.658 D/Mono    (14892): GC_BRIDGE waiting for bridge processing to finish
04-11 16:46:22.661 D/Mono    (14892): GC_TAR_BRIDGE bridges 424 objects 2303 colors 445 ignored 814 sccs 424 xref 150 cache 0/0 setup 0.16ms tarjan 2.39ms scc-setup 0.20ms gather-xref 0.06ms xref-setup 0.02ms cleanup 0.31ms
04-11 16:46:22.661 D/Mono    (14892): GC_BRIDGE: Complete, was running for 49.28ms
04-11 16:46:22.661 D/Mono    (14892): GC_MAJOR: (LOS overflow) time 27.89ms, stw 29.64ms los size: 2048K in use: 467K
04-11 16:46:22.661 D/Mono    (14892): GC_MAJOR_SWEEP: major size: 3936K in use: 2558K
```

But now when I run the app I do NOT see any of these types of messages when a GC is performed. I see output from ART, such as:

```
[art] Starting a blocking GC Explicit
[art] Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(72B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 1693KB/2MB, paused 712us total 30.887ms
```

When I use the environment.txt file to configure more verbose logging (e.g. MONO_LOG_LEVEL=info) then I get one additional line of output from MONO like:

```
[monodroid-gc] GC cleanup summary: 25 objects tested - resurrecting 25.
```

But this is not really useful to me. I want to see the information from GC_BRIDGE, GC_MAJOR, and GC_MAJOR_SWEEP. I have searched and searched and cannot find anyone else reporting this issue, but it seems that something changed in Xamarin.Android at some point.

Comment: Then you should report directly at GitHub, https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues

Comment: I appreciate the comment and will consider submitting an issue, but to be honest I wasn't sure this was necessarily a bug. I thought maybe it was just a change in default behavior or something, but you're probably right about it being a bug. Thanks.

Comment: It does sound like a change in default behavior (the more common complaint is that the output is too cluttered). But I can't find any option to control it. If you report it as a bug, in the new issue, link to this SO thread. And as a comment here, give link to the issue. There really needs to be some way to control this.